# Mobile menu with a sub-menu - How to make the whole <li> tag wraped in an <a> tag when having a button inside the <li> that opens the sub-menu

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a mobile menu - which some of it's list items have an other sub-menu with list items that should open when clicing the image (view image in the bottom of this post). 
I want to make the whole `<li>` clickable. 
an example for a simple code part without any sub-menu:

```
            <a href="#"><li> Boxing </li></a>
```

the `<a>` tag is wrapping the `<li>` what makes the whole `<li>` a link. 
The problem is when I have an image inserted (image for the submenu button), I cant get all the li to be lined to something.

This is one list item code:

```
            <a href="#" >
                <li>NFL 
                    <img src="strokes_for_menu.png"  id="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <a href="#" class="selected">
                            <li>Superbowl</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </a>
```

~ "NFL" leads to a page. When clicking on the image it opens the sub-menu with list items that lead to other pages.

**What is the solution for this?**

this is how it looks for now:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be wrapping `li` with an `a`. It should be the other way around.

Comment: But I want the whole bar to be a clickable as a link. 
If you have any other solution I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: That aside, I am still unable to understand what your problem is. Could you explain your problem and what you expect more clearly?

Comment: a clickeble li looks like this: 
<a href="#"><li> Boxing </li></a>
 - 
When I have an li with a submenu, I have to insert an image button that opens it. 
when having something like this - I can make the text the only link, and not the whole li.

Comment: Ok. give me a minute or two.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5wwakq4g/1/ . This is a quick but crude fiddle. Hope you get the idea. You would fire the sub-menu via Javascript in your code.

Comment: Check this updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5wwakq4g/3/ You will see the yellow background for the links to visualize it better.

Comment: I'll soon be on my desk and try it out. Tnx.

Comment: I saw what you did. 
I think that next time I'll do it using CSS. 
Your code is very short and works perfectly! 
The answer on the bottom worked for me. 
I copied you code for my next project :) !

Comment: Great! Just to remind you again that `ul` can contain only `li`. You should not wrap your `li` with `a`. This is not valid. Allowed parents for an `li` are only `ul` or `ol` or `menu`, nothing else. See the specs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context

Comment: Oh, good to know that it's wrong in that level! Thanks a-lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a css change to your `li` elements:

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Use native javascript or jquery to bind the click functions: (jquery example below)

```
$("li").click(function(){
  document.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
});
```

Store the URLs in a custom attribute in `li` tag:

```
<li url="http://example.com"></li>
<li url="http://test.com"></li>
```

Comment: I have a whole bunch of li-s which lead to different URLs.
I don't find it a solution. and If I use this on every single li it wont be efficient.

Comment: I'll soon be on my desk and try it out. tnx.